# Number of ways to color the numbers from 1 to 9 choosing from 3 colors for each one, such that no two numbers whose sum is odd are the same color

Tags: combinatorics

I've realised that odd and even numbers cannot have the same color, but two odds or two evens can.

I tried counting like this:
For number 1 we can choose from 3 colors, for 2 we have 2 colors, and for 3 we have two possibilities: if you choose the same color as number 1 (one color left, the same as number 1), there are 2 colors for number 4; if you choose a different color for number 3 (not the same color as number 1, also only one color left) there is only one color for number 4, 6 and 8, and all the other odd numbers 5, 7 and 9 have two colors each. Let's call this when you choose a different color than the color for the number one "locking".

You can lock the colors at the numbers 3, 5, 7 or 9. If you lock it at 3, the number of ways are $3*2*1*1*2*1*2*1*2$, at 5 $3*2*1*2*1*1*2*1*2$, at 7 $3*2*1*2*1*2*1*1*2$ and for 9 $3*2*1*2*1*2*1*2*1$, in each case 48, so $48*4=192$, but this is already over the solution. Why is this wrong, what have I double counted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good approach, but the mistake you're making is that you can also lock the colours at $4$, $6$ or $8$. If you don't lock the colours at $3$ then you have $2$ choices for $4$, but one of them is the colour that hasn't yet been used, and this will lock the colours.

So actually the number of ways that lock at $4$ is $3\times 2\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 2\times 1\times 2\times 1=24$, the number of ways to lock at $5$ is $3\times 2\times 1\times1\times 1\times1\times2\times1\times2=24$, but there are only $12$ ways to lock at $6$, $12$ for $7$, $6$ for $8$ and $6$ for $9$ (and $6$ more which never lock, i.e. only use two colours).

Comment: Oh, I see, that's why I didn't get the right solution. I really thought that no one would understand what I wrote, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: `I really thought that no one would understand what I wrote, but I guess I was wrong.`
If you think so while writing, maybe just rephrase?

Answer (score 6):

The colors used for coloring $D=\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ cannot be used for coloring $E=\{2,4,6,8\}$ and vice-versa. So we have two cases: either $D$ is monochromatic or $E$ is monochromatic. In the first case, once we pick the color for each element of $D$ we have $2^4$ ways for coloring $E$. In the second case, once we pick the color for the elements of $E$ we have $2^5$ ways for coloring the elements of $D$. We have counted twice the cases in which *both* $D$ and $E$ are monochromatic, hence the final outcome is

$$ 3\cdot 2^4+ 3\cdot 2^5 - 6 = \color{blue}{138}. $$

Comment: The 6 cases you subtracted are when $D$ and $E$ are both monochromatic but with distinct colors?

Comment: @MaxFt: if both $D$ and $E$ are monochromatic they still need to have different colors. Hence once we pick the color for $D$ ($3$ possible ways) we have $2$ ways for picking the color of $E$. This is the origin of the $-6$.

Comment: By monochromatic, do you mean that all elements from, let's say $D$, all have the same color? Don't we have the case where they can differ in color? For example, 1 blue, 2 red, 3 green. In this example 1 and 3 aren't the same color.

Comment: @AyyLmao: yes, of course, what else could *monochromatic* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Either odd or even numbers shall be of the same color. Excluding the cases when also the numbers of the other parity are monochromatic there are 
$$
(2^5-2+2^4-2)3=132
$$
such combinations. By adding 6 possible combinations with both parities being monochromatic one obtains as final answer the number
$$138.$$

Answer (score 1):

As you note "sum is odd" is equivalent to "have different parity". Thus, this can be considered a complete bipartite graph, K(5,5). There is a concept called the "chromatic polynomial", which is a polynomial that gives the number of coloring for different number of color. https://web.cs.elte.hu/blobs/diplomamunkak/mat/2009/hubai_tamas.pdf gives the formula for a bipartite graph as being

$chr(K_{n,m}, q) = \sum_k S(m, k)q(q − 1). . .(q − k + 1)(q − k)n$

Where S(m,k) are Stirling numbers of the second kind.

It 's probably easier in this case to simply find the number by inspection, but I thought you might be interested in the wider theory.